# Rewrite not working when "www" in URL

Tags: .htaccess

I used to have a website at www.roboticsguy.com, which I moved over to www.foxytronics.com. I want to redirect all requests from the old site to the new one. Here is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

redirect / http://www.foxytronics.com

rewritecond %{http_host} ^roboticsguy.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.foxytronics.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

This URL works:

[roboticsguy.com/test/](http://roboticsguy.com/test/)

This one doesn't:

[www.roboticsguy.com/test/](http://www.roboticsguy.com/test/)

What's the problem with the rewrite and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `rewritecond %{http_host} ^roboticsguy.com [nc]` means "only do the next bit if the domain name is roboticsguy.com". www.roboticsguy.com is not the same as roboticsguy.com.

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^roboticsguy.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.foxytronics.com/$1 [r=301,nc] 
rewritecond %{http_host} ^www.roboticsguy.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.foxytronics.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

or

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^(www.)?roboticsguy.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.foxytronics.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

should work.